# PowerShell ScheduledJob runs but does not save output or return data

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell Scheduled Job that runs daily to clear cache. This job runs and completes successfully on all stations in the environment other than one. The job runs and clears the cache but does not return output to Users\User1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\DailyClearCache\Output. Also, get-job returns nothing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Windows 10
PowerShell 5

```
[computer1]: PS C:\> Get-ScheduledJob

Id         Name            JobTriggers     Command                  Enabled                                                                         
--         ----            -----------     -------                  -------
1          DailyClearCache 1               C:\DailyClearCache.ps1   True   

[computer1]: PS C:\> Get-Job
[computer1]: PS C:\>
```

Comment: What cache? What does the script do? How is the task configured? Specifically the running user? Is the output logged somewhere else on the system? Perhaps in a different folder.

Comment: Hi, we need to know the contents of DailyClearCache.ps1 to see what it is doing to be able to assist.  Also, this may be better suited to Superuser.

Comment: Thanks guys. Turns out this is related to ERROR_NO_TRUST_SAM_ACCOUNT

1787 (0x6FB) error. Task scheduler shows the task does not run but the history tab gives "Task Scheduler failed to start ...Additional Data: Error Value: 2147944187". Convert 2147944187 to hex and take last 4 digits are Microsoft error code. Hoping this is the real issue as I can certainly resolve this.